Query improvement on computed column
I've got query:
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE tracker_id = :id
  AND is_deleted = 0
  AND (email LIKE LOWER(:text) OR phone LIKE :text)
LIMIT :startingPosition, 11

but sometimes it takes too long to execute.
I have two indexes

tracker_id and email
tracker_id and phone

but when making query based on the email it takes too long. Will the index take effect when there is LOWER function used? How could I improve this query

It is a bit weird that you are looking for a string, but don't know whether it is to be searched in phone numbers or in email addresses. It looks like you should be able to determine this before and then send the appropriate query on either phone or email to the DBMS.

By the way: LIMIT :startingPosition, 11 makes no sense without an ORDER BY clause. Without an ORDER BY, the query can return the rows in arbitrary order. This means that it is free to give you the same 11 rows again and again, no matter what "startingPosition" you give it. (And f I were the DBMS, I would do just that; get the 11 rows from cache that I just selected before.)

please edit your question to show (as text, not image) output of show create table customer and show some sample values for :text and sample data.

if the :text args start with a % MySQL can use a Index, so it was a FULL TABLE SCAN over all rows. that is the reason why your query is slow. You can also post sone search string to see if there a better query

Please include a few sample values of the parameter :text in the question.

Looking at the query, the line below caught my eye and could be the reason for the delay.
"AND (email LIKE LOWER(:text) OR phone LIKE :text)"
Do these 2 things, and try:
Instead of "OR" condition, use 2 separate queries (one for email & one for phone) using UNION ALL operator.  (It could return dups here, but just to diagnosis the cause, use UNION ALL).
Make sure the variable (:text) represents "starts with" pattern instead of "ends with".  If it's the later one, then it won't be use any indexes if available.
I'd start with this...
And since LOWER is deterministic function, it'd not affect.
